# Nopcommerce - How to display product specification attributes belonging to same group in a single line

Tags: nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce 2.65. Consider a particular product being available in multiple locations (one to many). nopCommerce allows you to create a specification attribute and add it multiple times per product. So I can do this,

```
Product A : Location: London
Product A : Location: Paris
Product A : Location: Tokyo
```

**However in product details view. It is displayed as:**

```
Product A
Location: London
Location: Paris
Location: Tokyo
```

**I am expecting it to be displayed as**

```
Product A
Locations: London,Paris,Tokyo
```

Has anyone done this before, how can guide how to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the view : `Views/Catalog/ProductSpecifications.cshtml`.

Comment: Thanks, I could customize this view and achieve the results I wanted.